# Plane with Animated Image?

Tags: animation, shaders, grease-pencil

I've been using grease pencil for a while - powerful tool, great for animation. I wanted to add a painted image behind the lines to act as a background, which can be easily done with a plane with an image attached to it, but I also wanted the background to be animated and this is where I'm having problems.

Is it possible to animate an image attached to a flat plane?

Comment: what kind of animation do you want? deform the plane? or play a movie instead an image?

Comment: Movie. I'd like to make a looping animation that uses images as frames.

Comment: Combine the images into a video file and select that video file in the image texture of that plane. Select the frame range and turn on "Auto Refresh" in the image texture node.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Also, you can place an image or video file into the backplate from the camera properties tab under "Background Images" if you want a simple way to put it in the camera view.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.